# Get Category name/slug for wp_Query on product-category to show product list according to category

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a woocommerce website, and i want to show product list according to a category on the product-category page i.e: `www.wesiteName.com/product-category/ladies`. I want to show all the ladies products on this link but how? My code didn't work.

I am using this function `woocommerce_page_title()` to get category name but it print the category name but didn't pass name in wp query don't know why.

```
if (is_product_category()) :
    $title = woocommerce_page_title();
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'product_cat'    => $title,
        'orderby'        => 'post_title',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

endif;
```

It shows all the products from all categories. I just want to show a particular product list according to a category.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$args = array(
'number'     => $number,
'orderby'    => 'title',
'order'      => 'ASC',
'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
'include'    => $ids
 );
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
$count = count($product_categories);
if ( $count > 0 ){
foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
    echo '<h4><a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . 
$product_category->name . '</a></h4>';
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                // 'terms' => 'white-wines'
                'terms' => $product_category->slug
            )
        ),
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby' => 'title,'
    );
    $products = new WP_Query( $args );
    echo "<ul>";
    while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
        $products->the_post();
        ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    }
    }
```

Hope its working for you

Comment: this shows all product from all category i want to show particular one